# ¿Está bien utilizar Emojis en las publicaciones? 

Tags: discusión, revisión-de-pregunta

Yo estaba en la cola de revisiones, como siempre, pero me apareció una pregunta con Emojis.

[Abrir la cámara frontal y trasera en Swift 3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46460/abrir-c%C3%A1mara-frontal-y-trasera-en-swift-3)

Al final de la pregunta me encuentro con este mensaje:

> ## ¿Que tengo hacer para lograr lo que quiero?
>
> Nota: Para los que ven un cuadradito blanco en vez del Emoji, dejo una imagen.
>
> [image: Emoji]

Mi decisión, por respeto al autor, fue dejar el Emoji, pero lo transladé al inicio de la pregunta, quedando de esta manera.

> ## Ya tengo la cámara hecha y esta abre solo la cámara frontal, pero quiero crear un botón para abrir la cámara trasera o frontal.

Esta vez mantuve el Emoji, pensé que que si lo quito, el autor se podría haber enojado.

¿Es correcto utilizar este tipo de caritas en las publicaciones, preguntas o respuestas?

Comment: p̮͎̽ͧ̇o̱̪͓͕͛͆ͬ̍͗̐̑r͔̹̬̼͂̎͐̾̓ͤ̌ ͎͓̤͔͖̒͒ͣ̋ͭ̏ͧq̲ͩ͒ͦͧ̊͂ͪû͕̺̯̬̙̬̫̤ͥͅē̪̤̜̤͎͂ͯͦ̉ͯ̒͊̓ͅ ̲̱̗̝͕̘̺̠͙̒͆̌͒n̗̼̳͓̭̟ͦo͓̱̭̯͊̾̎̈́ͯͨ̓̇ͥͅ?̠͚̠̔

Comment: ................... son caracteres Unicode, son validos, y hay casos en que podrian necesitarse. ver esto relacionado: [     ?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342024/)

Comment: Al margen queda el abuso puntual de un usuario... en ese caso ponga una bandera al moderador y deje que ellos se ocupen de el :P

Comment: Yo pienso que si ayudan a comprender la pregunta, sí. Si no, entonces no tiene sentido alguno.

Comment: Como en con cualquier otro caracter, sea ASCII, UNICODE o de cualquier otro tipo, sólo deberían incluirse cuando se requieren. En particular en el caso de emoji, debe considerarse sus peculiaridades. Salvo que la pregunta sea sobre el uso de emojis, deberían evitarse.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

También hice una [pregunta en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1338/78) sobre los emojis en otra pregunta en el sitio principal (SOes).

Pienso que no deberia permitirse, crea mucha distracción. Habrá que ver una pregunta en la cual el uso de los emojis sea aceptable, pero no he encontrado ninguna hasta el momento<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> La pregunta enlazada era una pregunta *no relacionada a programación*.

Comment: Aquí tienes un ejemplo "¿Por que este carácter:  se ve así � luego de almacenarlo en mi base de datos?".  Esta podría ser una pregunta on-topic aquí.

Comment: @EmanuelVe, **no estoy de acuerdo en que los títulos tenga emojis**, las publicaciones "como en tu caso" se puede redactar de otra manera: Ejemplo: Título: ¿Cómo guardar caracteres especiales en base de datos?
Cuerpo: He intentado X para guardar este caracter: � _(o inserte la imagen del caracter a guardar)_. La comunidad en todo caso es quien genera sus aportes. Mi opinión no es absoluta :)

Comment: Esto no es una red social de amigos que hablan, sino más bien un lugar técnico donde se preguntan cosas sobre problemas que tenemos. Supongo que la mayoría de los que estamos en SOes es porque nos dedicamos al código laboralmente. Todo lo que distrae, nos aleja del objetivo del sitio que tan solo resolver problemas y/o dudas.

Comment: Marc, SO es, entre otras cosas, una red social. Sirve, por ejemplo, para ponerte en contacto con empresas que puedan estar interesadas en contratarte. Y hay, entre otros, amigos que hablan. Y también hay mucha gente que no se dedica al código laboralmente, como por ejemplo estudiantes, Y en el que se hacen cosas que no son resolver problemas y dudas, como concursos. Veamos las cosas con amplitud de miras, amplitud de miras que debe incluir respetar a quien gusta de usar emojis.

Comment: Yo sólo he encontrado [una pregunta](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202143/i-included-emoji-in-my-password-and-now-i-cant-log-in-to-my-account-on-yosemite) en que el uso de emoji en el título y/o en la pregunta esté justificado. Y aún así no lo usa en el título.

Answer (score 4):

En el fondo es tu criterio, pero estoy seguro que si tu no lo borras, alguien mas lo hará.
En la conversación sobre el grado hasta que preguntas y respuestas deberían ser reducido a pura información quedó claro que la comunidad de **SE** rechaza salutaciones y saludos y la comunidad de **SOes** se inclina a lo mismo.

Es posible que eso cambia dependiente de lo que prefiere la mayoría de los usuarios a largo plazo, pero por ahora no veo señales que la gente necesitan emojis aquí.

La ventaja del sistema de moderación de comunidad es que en el caso de duda puedes simplemente no hacer nada y dejar la decisión a otro usuario.

Yo personalmente creo que emojis no tienen lugar en SO. Cualquier contenido externo siempre es complicado, y emojis para mi no tienen un valor social suficiente para ser indispensable.

Answer (score -1):

## SI! solo son caracteres unicode

Hay algunos casos donde se necesitan...

### T̪̹̦̩͉̟͇͕͎̬͇͔͍̟ͅo̫̥̼̱̠̳̘͉̫̤̤̖͍̲̯d͍͖͓̯̭̟̦͖̼͎̼̱̹̲̳̬͓͎͍o̥̥̣͓̲̪̠͖͇͍̜̗̭ṣ͖̟̟̞̦̦̪̠̯̭̩̳͈̭͓̖ ̠̮̗̭̬̠̜͇l͔̩͈͈͚̣̬̯ͅo̰̝̱s̳̺͚̲̟͎̺͖͖̫̬͍̫̠͚͙̲̬ͅ ̝͙͚̙͇̤͇̜̤j̳͔̞̲̪̱̲̯͈̝̭̫̟u̻̯͇̩̻̮̗͔̺̘̻̣͕͈̭͈̣̩e͇̞̖̙̱͙̩͕͔̪̼͖̠g͉̲̼̬̭o͙̤̞̬̱̹͉̜̞͔̱̩̫ͅs̳̪͉̣̖̻̤͚̝̙̘͙̝̠̖̰̙̝͕ ̭͈̦͇͎̫̮͚͇̲̺̮̻͈d̠̮̳͉̳̣̟̖̻e͍̙̜̯̰ ̭͍̘̦̣̗c̠͙̯̩a̼̣̜̣̥̣͎̻̙̝͈͕̹̞̦͎r͕͙͙̙̣͕̩̜̮̙͍̦a͙̳͍̹̼̭̰͇̯̝̖̱̺̩̤ͅͅc̟̩̟̥̣͇t̗̗̮̠͎͔̻̮̝͙̠̥̭͓̟̬͙e͙̩͚̖ͅr͈͕̮̦̤̘̭̤e̝̻̮̥͖̯̥̦̩̲̥͓s̳̺̹̗̠̠̦̞̼̗̝ ̙̞̪͔̬͙̱͎̼̤̜̜͖͓u͎̞͈͓̦̰͇̱̞͓͍̞͔̱͇n̟̰̻̝̠̺̺͚̙ͅi̮̱̻̜̩̰̭͙̬̬͖̳c̯͕̮̫̖̼̠̯̖̝ͅͅo͔̮̣͙̩ͅͅd̪̺͖̗̰̙̩̲̦̬͍͖̬e͖̭̗̜̬̰͖̱͍̤͓̳͍͇͍ ̩̙̠̰̥͎d͉̼͈̝̞͚̥̼͈e͖̹̫̝̼̟̮̘̱̖͔͉̩̬̲̝̬b̥̘̤̬e̦̤̮͈̤͓n̙̯͍̲̙͇̗̹̹̫̠̻̗̫̱ͅͅ ̥̱̩̲̹̞̩̠̖͕̰̣͉͚̘͓e̳̳͔̫s̹͚̥̮̬͚̟̤̺t̙̫̮̱̠͍͎̳a̙̮̲͈̳͚͈͎r̙͓̖̦͖̬̟̺̘͉̟̺̠̬̲͍̬ͅ ̙̫̪̻͉̳̬ͅp̜̩͎e̺̖͈̣̥͉̘̻̻̣̥̰̯̫̰̥͚r̠̘͈͇͍̪̦̬̠̙͚m̤̣̗̱̜̪̟̺̟̬͇i̪͎̯͇͕͙̩̲̙͕̤̞̥̱t̥̗̫̮̞̥̝͉͓̖̹̣̻̻̝̭i͙̟̬̼̤d͍̗̼o̳̱̩̟̠̟̺̭̝͓̦̭͓͕̼̺ͅͅs͚̰̺͍̮͓̻͙̹̯͖̬͈̖̜̙͉̲!̪̟̘̳̖̪͎̠̹̦͙̲̻̩̞̻

Comment: `si` y `hay algunos casos` son diferentes situaciones.

Comment: @Mauricio para poder incluirlo en _algunos casos_, se necesita que estén permitidos, así que no son diferentes situaciones, hay una dependencia entre esas situaciones.

Comment: ¿Por qué tanto voto negativo? Yo no le veo nada de moron a esta respuesta. Parece que hay gente que todo lo ve negativo.

Comment: @guzgarcia mi teoría: nos encanta prohibir cosas, incluso si no están causando problemas XD.

Comment: El eterno problema de la humanidad :D