# Implementar emojis en el chat

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, chat

Durante algunos días he utilizado el chat para preguntar a las personas que ahí se encuentran sobre ciertas dudas que considero no ameritan abrir una pregunta como tal, de igual forma muchos de nosotros usamos el chat para seguir aprendiendo compartiendo enlaces a recursos o tutoriales.

Utilizamos el chat como una extensión de SO y que considero nos permite interactuar de una forma **rápida** con la comunidad. Entiendo que existen temas que de resolverse aportarían una mayor utilidad que un simple dibujo pero lo que pretendo es simplemente hacer de este un lugar en el que estemos contentos de estar y permanecer ... Hacerlo más nuestro Stack Overflow.

Ahora, existe una pregunta sobre emojis pero en preguntas, no en el chat:

[👉¿Está bien utilizar Emojis en las publicaciones? 👈](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1340/est%c3%a1-bien-utilizar-emojis-en-las-publicaciones)

Supongo que no estará tan relacionada con lo que aquí planteo.

Si alguno de ustedes está de acuerdo con la propuesta. ¿Cuál es el proceso que deberíamos de seguir para la implementación?

Me gustaría saber su opinión y las desventajas o ventajas que implica.

Saludos.

Comment: Considerando que los emojis están por todo lado: Android, iOS, Windows, aplicaciones en general, sería interesante ver si es posible implementar eso en la sala de chat :D

Comment: Tengo la impresión de que las preguntas sobre [tag:característica-nueva] sobre chat son "ignoradas" en cuanto a la asignación de presupuesto me imagino que la excepción es que se trate de un asunto que tenga que ver con seguridad/privacidad/evitar abusos. Tan sólo véase https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chat+feature-request sólo un par de publicaciones "recientes" (primera página) tienen etiqueta de estado.

Comment: Por primera página me refiero a las primeras 50.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con proceso para la implementación? En el chat ya se pueden usar emojis (o iconos de Unicode). ¡También en los comentarios ! Aunque es más sencillo desde el teléfono móvil. Si lo que quieres es tener acceso rápido a los mismos desde un PC, eso ya es otra historia. (Aunque seguro que debe existir alguna extensión que te permita ponerlos rápido). Otra cosa es que sea conveniente o no.

Comment: Tengo entendido que [sí se puede](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50716639#50716639), y estoy de acuerdo con @AlvaroMontoro, un acceso directo es algo completamente diferente :D

Comment: Desconocia que existe un script que ayuda a esto. Es lo que proponia, pero ya existe.

Answer (score 9):

Como se mencionó en los comentarios, el chat soporta UNICODE y este incluye Emojis. Los usuarios de Windows 10 pueden insertar Emojis sin necesidad de extensiones, para ello basta con hacer clic al mismo tiempo en las teclas Windows y punto <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>. Se mostrará un menú emergente como el siguiente:

[image]

Seguramente otros sistemas operativos modernos tienen cosas similares

Comment: Que interesante, no sabía esto de Windows 10!